# Best way to replace all characters from left to right?

Tags: javascript

I have this string that looks like this:

```
1940-01-01T07:00:00.000Z
```

and I'm trying to convert it to this:

```
1940-01-01T00:00:00
```

I'm not sure how to replace all characters starting at letter **T** by 00:00:00

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot in advance.

This is my code so far, but doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
"1940-01-01T07:00:00.000Z".replace("T", "T00:00:00");
```

Comment: If your dates are in a consistent format you don't need to do any pattern matching and you'll get the most performance out of [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring): `'1940-01-01T07:00:00.000Z'.substring(0, 11) + '00:00:00'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
"1940-01-01T07:00:00.000Z".replace(/T.+$/, "T00:00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring with replace like this

```
var a = "1940-01-01T07:00:00.000Z";
alert(a.replace(a.substring(a.indexOf("T")+1,a.length), "00:00:00"));
```

fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vdadekvL/29/

Answer (score 0):

Your code replaces the `T` with `T00:00:00` resulting in `1940-01-01T00:00:0007:00:00.000Z`

For your example data, what you could do is split on a `T`. Then take the first item from the resulting arary and append `T00:00:00`

```js
let result = "1940-01-01T07:00:00.000Z".split('T')[0] + "T00:00:00";
console.log(result);
```